# Inserting data into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

After having created a temporary table and declaring the data types like so;

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
ID int,
Date datetime,
Name char(20))
```

How do I then insert the relevant data which is already held on a physical table within the database?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Date, Name) 
SELECT id, date, name 
FROM physical_table
```

Comment: Remember to drop the table once your done with it, otherwise you might run into the "There is already an object named '#TempTable' in the database." error (should you run the query again...)

Comment: @alexsuslin it is connected, don't be like that 

Comment: prefix with: `drop table if exists #MyTable`

Answer (score 142):

To insert all data from all columns, just use this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OriginalTable
```

Don't forget to `DROP` the temporary table after you have finished with it and *before* you try creating it again:

```
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: I like this because I don't have to `CREATE` the `#TempTable`

Comment: can prefix with: `drop table if exists #MyTable`

Answer (score 80):

```
SELECT  ID , Date , Name into #temp from [TableName]
```

Answer (score 49):

My way of `Insert` in SQL Server. Also I usually check if a temporary table exists.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #MyTable

SELECT b.Val as 'bVals'
  INTO #MyTable
FROM OtherTable as b
```

Comment: also: `drop table if exists #MyTable`

Answer (score 23):

I have provided two approaches to solve the same issue,

> Solution 1: This approach includes 2 steps, first create a temporary table with
>   specified data type, next insert the value from the existing data
>   table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStudent(tempID  int, tempName  varchar(MAX) )
INSERT INTO #TempStudent(tempID, tempName) SELECT id, studName FROM students where id =1

SELECT * FROM #TempStudent
```

> Solution 2: This approach is simple, where you can directly insert the values to
>   temporary table, where automatically the system take care of creating
>   the temp table with the same data type of original table.

```
SELECT id, studName  INTO #TempStudent FROM students where id =1

SELECT * FROM #TempStudent
```

Comment: While I recognize that this is a temp table, I still would never recommend someone use varchar(MAX).

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable
FROM table
```

Comment: Simplest answer here really. You can also use dbo.MyTable and it will be a permanent table. Easy peasy

Answer (score 9):

After you create the temp table you would just do a normal `INSERT INTO () SELECT FROM`

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (id, Date, Name)
SELECT t.id, t.Date, t.Name
FROM yourTable t
```

Answer (score 8):

The right query:

```
drop table #tmp_table

select new_acc_no, count(new_acc_no) as count1
into #tmp_table
from table
where unit_id = '0007' 
group by unit_id, new_acc_no
having count(new_acc_no) > 1
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. You took this information from somewhere else. Removing `new_acc_no`, `unit_id = '0007'`, `group by`, `having count(new_acc_no) > 1`, etc transforms the answer in an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15762663/1476885

Answer (score 7):

```
insert into #temptable (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3 from othertable
```

Note that this is considered poor practice:

```
insert into #temptable 
select col1, col2, col3 from othertable
```

If the definition of the temp table were to change, the code could fail at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Basic operation of Temporary table is given below, modify and use as per your requirements,

**-- CREATE A TEMP TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempEmployeeTable(tempUserID  varchar(MAX), tempUserName  varchar(MAX) )
```

**-- INSERT VALUE INTO A TEMP TABLE**

```
INSERT INTO #MyTempEmployeeTable(tempUserID,tempUserName) SELECT userid,username FROM users where userid =21
```

**-- QUERY A TEMP TABLE [This will work only in same session/Instance, not in other user session instance]**

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTempEmployeeTable
```

**-- DELETE VALUE IN TEMP TABLE**

```
DELETE FROM #MyTempEmployeeTable
```

**-- DROP A TEMP TABLE**

```
DROP TABLE #MyTempEmployeeTable
```

Comment: While I recognize that this is a temp table, I still would never recommend someone use varchar(MAX).

Comment: @bp_  This is a generalized sample snippet which explains the user and User can specify the data type and its size based on their application requirements.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable(ID, Date, Name)
SELECT OtherID, OtherDate, OtherName FROM PhysicalTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert #temptable
select idfield, datefield, namefield from yourrealtable
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above mentioned answers will almost fullfill the purpose. However, You need to drop the temp table after all the operation on it. You can follow-

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Date, Name) 
SELECT id, date, name 
FROM physical_table;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```